# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named psycopg2 after installing package on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pip, psycopg2

I'm on macOS Monterrey version 12.4. I've installed the package `psycopg2` with the command `pip3 install psycopg2`. The output of the installation is

```bash
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.9.3)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

However when I try to run my python script using `python3 my_script.py`, which has `import psycopg2`, I get the error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert_update_user_flags.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

How do I fix it? I'm not sure why python3 can't find the package after installation with pip3

Comment: what's the output of `which python3`? can you try `/usr/local/bin/python3.9 my_script.py`? it's possible `python3` is not pointing to the correct version that has the package installed

Comment: `which python3` returns `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Do I need to change `python3` to point to `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9`?

Comment: you can try `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 my_script.py` to see if it works; in general, it's best to install packages to virtual environments, then once you activate the virtual environment, you will know for sure you are using the correct python.

Comment: ahh ok I have no knowledge on setting virtual environments. I'll have to read up on those.